# ERROR 1064 (42000): While Declaring a Cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am Trying to create stored procedure in MYSQLand getting below error.
I googled about it but no solution found please help me in this.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_PROCESS_USER_STG ( OUT    O_error_msg         VARCHAR(3000),
                                                 OUT    O_status            VARCHAR(300),
                                                 IN     I_uploaded_by       INT (10))
BEGIN
   declare L_program_name            VARCHAR(100);

   declare L_login_id              INT(10)     ;
   declare L_password              VARCHAR(100);
   declare L_first_name            VARCHAR(100); 
   declare L_last_name             VARCHAR(100); 
   declare L_privilege_group_id    INT(10)     ;
   declare L_group_id              INT(10)     ;
   declare L_message               VARCHAR(100); 
   declare L_date_of_upload        TIMESTAMP   ;
   declare L_date_of_update        TIMESTAMP   ;
   declare L_uploaded_by           INT(10)     ;
   declare L_status                VARCHAR(10) ; 
   declare L_error_msg             VARCHAR(100), 

   declare L_finished              INT(1)        DEFAULT 0;

   declare C_user_stg CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT LOGIN_ID, 
             PASSWORD, 
             FIRST_NAME, 
             LAST_NAME, 
             PRIVILEGE_GROUP_ID, 
             GROUP_ID
        FROM uploaded_user_stg 
       where UPLOADED_BY = I_uploaded_by 
         and status in ( 'NEW' , 'UPDATE' );

   declare CONTINUE HANDLER 
       FOR NOT FOUND SET L_finished = 1;

   OPEN C_user_stg;

   get_user: LOOP

      FETCH C_user_stg INTO L_login_id          ,
                            L_password          ,
                            L_first_name        ,
                            L_last_name         ,
                            L_privilege_group_id,
                            L_group_id          ;

      IF L_finished = 1 THEN 
         LEAVE get_user;
      END IF;

 -- build email list
      CALL P_CREATE_USER ( L_message ,
                           L_status    ,
                           L_login_id  ,
                           L_password  ,
                           L_first_name,
                           L_last_name ,
                           L_privilege_group_id,
                           L_group_id  )

      UPDATE uploaded_user_stg 
         SET status         = L_status,
             error_msg      = L_message
             date_of_update = now();
       where login_id  = L_login_id;

   END LOOP get_email;

   CLOSE get_user;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting Below error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that on for the right syntax to use near '
>
> declare L_finished              INT(1)        DEFAULT 0;
>
> declare C_' at line 18

Comment: remove argument(1) from INT , and try to run.

Answer (score 0):

**Change this from:**

```
declare L_error_msg             VARCHAR(100),
```

to

```
declare L_error_msg             VARCHAR(100);
```

Comment: Replace the comma.